# How do I display a table to list using distinct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an orders table that I want to display the content of in the view. I would normally do this like:

```
return View(db.Orders.ToList());
```

then call the fields I wish to display in the view:

```
<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderNum)
    </th>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreateDate)
    </td>
    ....
</th>
```

However, what do I do if I want to display the same table `ToList()` but I want to make it so that I return `DISTINCT` `OrderNum` rows. Here is what I have tried:

```
var UserOrders = (from uo in db.Orders select new { uo.OrderNum, uo.CreateDate, ... }).ToList();
        var result = UserOrders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderNum).Select(y=>y.First());
        return View(result.ToList());
```

Which returned the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType9`10[System.Int32,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean],Project.Models.DeliveryOption]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.Order]'.

and

```
return View(db.Orders.ToList().Distinct());
```

Which ignores the distinct command on the end. As it returns all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt was close, but you didn't need to project to an anonymous type This should work:

```
        var result = db.Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderNum)
            .Select(y=>y.FirstOrDefault());
        return View(result.ToList());
```

I'm using `FirstOrDefault()` because last I checked Entity Framework doesn't like to do `.First()` inside of a query expression.

The reason `.ToList().Distinct()` didn't work is because the program doesn't know what makes two `Order`s "equal", so it defaults to looking at their memory address. Since all the returned objects have different memory addresses, it thinks they're all unique.

Answer (score 1):

You are projecting the result to **anonymous type** which is causing problem as your view is strongly bound with `IEnumerable<Project.Models.Order>` type not `IEnumerable<Anonymous>`, you should project to `Order` after grouping :

```
var UserOrders = (from uo in db.Orders 
                  select new Order 
                             { 
                                 OrderNum =uo.OrderNum, 
                                 CreatedDate = uo.CreateDate, ... 
                              }).ToList();
```

now your next code will return the proper type of result:

```
var result = UserOrders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderNum).Select(y=>y.First());
return View(result.ToList());
```

You can actually do the grouping thing on database side if you don't project and materialize the result by doing:

```
var reuslt = db.Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderNum)
                      .Select(x=>x.First());
return View(result.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the need for Anonymous types. Something like the following should work:

```
return View(db.Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.OrderNum).Select(y=>y.First()).ToList());
```

Comment: No need for that final `Distinct()` when you've already done the GroupBy